# Qt tree view with Pyside

Tags: python, qt, treeview, directory, pyside

I have two folders in program directory. I need them to show in tree view, they should be expandable. How can I define what folder will be in tree view? If anyone canshow me an easy example. I know names of folders.

I´m using Python 2.7 and Win 8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `QTreeView` and `QFileSystemModel`:

```
model = QFileSystemModel();
model.setRootPath(QDir.currentPath())
tree = QTreeView()
tree.setModel(model)
tree.setRootIndex(model.index(QDir.currentPath()))
tree.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. Other thing, now I need to disable the "type" and "size" columns. I´m sorry for these questions but I´m very new to this and time is running out.

Comment: Use `QTreeView.hideColumn()`.

Comment: Ok now I see my files, but I cant open them, any idea why?

Comment: `QDesktopServices.openUrl(QUrl("path/yourFile.txt"))` should open the file with its default application. I don't know why but I need to use '/' in the path even on windows...

Comment: But i have unkown number of files with pre unknown names. I need to open them on click in tree view. Is it possible?

Comment: See the Qt documentation to know how to get the file path.