# Qtreeview clickable files, python

Tags: python, qt, treeview

Hi I have some files in treeview, but I can´t click/open them. 
Can you explain how to do it? Or give me an example.
I dont know many files will be there nor their names. Thank you.

Im using python 2.7

Comment: better yet, can i connect somehow qtree when i click on something

Comment: Already answered on the other topic: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472746/qt-tree-view-with-pyside](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472746/qt-tree-view-with-pyside)